# Access to an i2c device used by the kernel, from user space

Tags: kernel, users, devices

On my ARM board there's an I2C PMIC used by the kernel:

```
# i2cdetect -r 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

But I cannot read anything:

```
# i2cget -a 1 0x33 0x25 b
Error: Could not set address to 0x33: Device or resource busy
```

I'm afraid this is because the kernel is using the device.
Is there a way to read it? I mean some mutex or similar to access the device when it's not "busy"?

the goal is to read its registers to get, for example, voltages and error flags.

Comment: `i2ctransfer -f -y 1 w1@0x33 0x25 r1` seems to do the trick. But I cannot read using `i2c-dev.h`.

Answer (score 0):

ARM board, there's an I2C PMIC used by the kernel so your ARM board does not give you access to use this i2c bus.

This is the answer to your question.

So use another i2c BUS.

```
$ i2cdetect -r 2
$ i2cdetect -r 3
```

Comment: The question was about how to read that specific device (PMIC) when the kernel is not accessing it. Changing the bus is not a solution.

Comment: -f
Force access to the device even if it is already busy. By default, i2cget will refuse to access a device that is already under the control of a kernel driver. Using this flag is dangerous, it can seriously confuse the kernel driver in question. It can also cause i2cget to return an invalid value. So use it at your own risk and only if you know what you're doing. Synopsis: i2cget [-f] [-y] i2cbus chip-address [data-address [mode]]
i2cget -V